# Using <thread> in code which is included in C++/CLI code. Looking for a better solution

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++-cli

native C++ "a.h":

```
#include <thread>

class a
{
    //... 
private:
    // ...
    std::mutex mutex;
};
```

C++/CLI:

```
#include "a.h" // error cause thread is included
```

my solution:

native C++ "a.h":

```
class a
{
    a();
    ~a();
    //... 
private:
    // ...
    void* mutex;
};
```

"a.cpp"

```
#include <thread>

a::a()
{
    mutex = new std::mutex;
}

~a::a()
{
    delete mutex;
}
```

C++/CLI:

```
#include "a.h" // no error
```

1. How to do this without dynamic memory allocation?
2. Is this safe? I somehow use wrapped stuff from < thread > in C++/CLI environment, just not in the header.
3. Is there a better approach? The new/delete and a cast on every use seems bad. I want to have one mutex per object of the class.

Comment: when asking for a better solution you need to explain what you want to achieve, not only show your solution. Without dynamic memory allocation? Just use a `mutex` instead of a `mutex*`?

Comment: "Just use a mutex instead of a mutex*"
Ok. How?

Comment: PIMPL idiom. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl

Comment: Can you use Standard C++ Libraries in C++/CLI?

Comment: It is formally illegal, you are not allowed to assume that .NET code uses an operating system thread.  It depends on the host, it is technically possible that it uses a fiber instead of a thread.  That is not actually something to deeply worry about, "green threads" were popular in the previous century and put to pasture by the multi-core revolution.  But the rule stands, your mutex isn't going to work at all if it is a fiber.  You'll need to hide the implementation detail from the C++/CLI compiler, standard techniques are an abstract interface or the pimpl idiom.

Answer (score -1):

Templates are here to help you out!

a.h:

```
template <class MutextType>
class a
{
    //... 
private:
    // ...
    MutextType mutex;
};
```

And then, in your main or wherever:

```
#inculde <thread>
//...
a<std::mutex> instance;
```

And you can also use using statements to clean up if you'd like, for cleaner code:

```
#inculde <thread>
//...
using MutexA = a<std::mutex>;
//...
MutexA instance;
```